# How to make wallpaper image for android tablets

Tags: android, tablet, galaxy-tab, xoom

Now I'm making wallpaper image for android tablet devices like Motorola Xoom or Galaxy Tab.

In android phones, typically wallpaper image size is 2 * screenWidth x screenHeight, but in Motorola Xoom it doesn't seem right because it automatically centered and scaled in weird way.

Is there anyone who knows about the exact image size for these devices or mechanism of wallpaper manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Super TFT screen like the newer HTC phones, your phone has good (not great) black levels, sharp lines, and fairly good colors. Something with some black will be good, but don’t overdo is as you might notice some bluish tones when the brightness is cranked up. You can however do more intricate images thanks to the high sharpness of the screen. For regular LCDs, just avoid a lot of black and it should look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally,

1. the Height of the wallpaper should match with the height of the device (or some multiple)
2. the width can be anything more than the width of the device (keeping the aspect ratio and point 1 in mind)

The android launcher will automatically center the image and then divide the image across all its home screens, let us illustrate this with an example:

Say if there are 3 homescreens, the screen will focus at the center right away and if you flick towards the left or the right, it will scroll to that screen. In other words it the homescreen wallpaper will move 2 times. 
(Taking that logic forward, if we have 5 screens, we will be able to move 4 times, **if there are n screens, one is able to move n-1 times!**)

This is how the formula works:

> device_screenwidth + (number_of_homescreens - 1) x distance_moved =
>   image_width

Say we have an image with height = 800 pixels and width 1280 pixels, applying the formula

> => 1280 + (3-1) x distance_moved = 2000
>
> => distance_moved = (2000-1280)/2 = 720/2 = 360

in other words, the central 1280 pixels of the walpaper are displayed first, but every time you flick left or right the walpaper shifts by 360 pixels at a time.

This is how the wallpaper is displayed over the 3 screens:

**screen 1:** 0 to 1280 pixels

**screen 2:** 360 to 1640 pixels (1280 + 360) (This is the default home screen)

**screen 3:** 720 to 2000 pixels (1640 + 360)

That is how an image/wallpaper with a width of 2000 pixels and a height which is the same as that of the device (800) is mapped across 3 home screens on a device with a resolution of 800x1280 pixels